# VBA .range("Can a formula go here?")

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

My end goal is to have the users select the range they would like to duplicate from a dropdown list and then upon clicking the "add" button, it will paste onto the sheet.

My ranges are named in the fashion of WorkSheet_RangeName, so for example the section for "Oil Furnace" will have the named ranged of "DataInput_OilFurnace".  Thus all my ranges will start with "DataInput_" and the spaces will need to be removed.

```
Sub AddExtraSection()

Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
Dim addSection As Range

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Data Input")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Add Extra Section")
Set addSection = Worksheets("Add Extra Section").Range("C3").Formula = _
"=""DataInput_""&SUBSTITUTE($C$3, "" "", """")"

copySheet.range(addSection).Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

If I can't use a formula, can I have the range name be a specific cell (as in, I have a formula beneath my dropdown that populates with the name of the Range)?

```
Set addSection = Worksheets("Add Extra Section").ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Formula = "=INDIRECT($C$4)"
```

I am very new to VBA so if all this seems like cobbled together half-guesses...it's because it is!  Thank you for any and all help!

***EDIT - SOLUTION***

a.k.a A range cannot have a formula within it and I needed to fix my set addSection

```
Sub AddExtraSection()

Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
Dim addSection As range

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Data Input")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Add Extra Section")
Set addSection = copySheet.range("C3")
addSection.Formula = "=""DataInput_""&SUBSTITUTE('Add Extra Section'!C3,"" "","""")"

copySheet.range(addSection).Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Comment: The string literal in `Range("something")` can be anything Excel can understand as referring to a range of cells: `"A1"`, `"A1:B12"`, `"$A:$B"`, `"SomeNamedRange"`, whatever. But no, not a formula.

Comment: Phooey.  Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting an error? I would think your `pasteSheet.Cells(...` line may throw an error.  See how you added the sheet name before `.Cells()`? You should always do that with `Rows()` and `Columns()` too, so that line would be: `pasteSheet.Cells(pasteSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial`.

Also, you can't do `mySheet.Range([formula])`. That needs to be broken up.  You would instead want to do

```
Set addSection = Worksheets("Add Extra Section").Range("C3")
addSection.Formula = "=""DataInput_""&SUBSTITUTE($C$3, "" "", """")"
```

I *think* that should do it for you.  Also a quick note, if you are doing `PasteSpecial` just to get the value pasted, a slightly quicker way is to set the ranges equal to eachother, thus avoiding the use of the clipboard:

`Range([destination range]).Value = Range([range to copy]).Value`

So, try this:

```
Sub AddExtraSection()

Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
Dim addSection As Range

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Data Input")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Add Extra Section")
Set addSection = pasteSheet.Range("C3")
addSection.Formula = "=""DataInput_""&SUBSTITUTE($C$3, "" "", """")"

pasteSheet.Cells(pasteSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = addSection.Value
End Sub
```

Edit: Per comments below, we can tighten the code up and make it a little more clear.

```
Sub AddExtraSection()

Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Add Extra Section")
'Next line will put "DataInput_[RANGE NAME]" in cell C3 of "Data Input" worksheet
Worksheets("Data Input").Range("C3").Formula = "=""DataInput_""&SUBSTITUTE('Add Extra Section'!$C$3, "" "", """")"

pasteSheet.Cells(pasteSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = _
    Worksheets("Data Input").Range("C3").Value
End Sub
```

We never really used the `copySheet`, so I removed that. Also, unless you plan on expanding this macro out, having `pasteSheet` and `addSection` adds confusion, so I tried to keep it simple.

On your Data Input sheet, we want to get the named range listed in cell C3.

The named range is listed in "Add Extra Section" sheet, cell C3. Take that string and remove spaces.  Then, add "DataInput_" to the beginning.  This is what the `...Formula =` line does. (Look at the formula backwards, Excel will first substitute the spaces out, and then concatenate that with "DataInput_").

Then, finally, take the "DataInput_[NAMED RANGE]" string, and put that in your "Add Extra Section"'s last row +1.

Edit2: Sorry, but thinking about this, an even better way would be to avoid using the worksheet, and do the work in VBA itself:

```
Sub updateNamedRange()
Dim destinationCell As Range, inputCell As Range

Set destinationCell = Worksheets("Add Extra Section").Cells(Worksheets("Add Extra Section").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Set inputCell = Worksheets("Add Extra Section").Cells(3, 3)

destinationCell.Value = "DataInput_" & WorksheetFunction.Substitute(inputCell, " ", "")

End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't that formula going to be a circular reference?

Comment: @Comintern - Maybe, to be honest I didn't really check the formula, but was just noting how you would do it in VBA. I think perhaps the `$C$3` is referring to another sheet? Maybe it should be `"=""DataInput_""&SUBSTITUTE('Data Input'!$C$3, "" "", """")"`?

Comment: Hard to tell what's intended I guess, but it can't just be `$C$3` if it's going into `.Range("C3")`.

Comment: Hello BruceWayne!  Thank you for helping!  When I enter your code, there are no errors (yay!) but now it just fills in with "0".

Comment: Hi again, thank you both for help!  I just updated the 'Data Input'!$C$3 and it's moving in the right direction!  The formula is working, but it is not pulling from the dropdown on Add Extra Section.  Would I enter "=""DataInput_""&SUBSTITUTE('Add Extra Section'!$C$3, "" "", """")" ?

When I do, however, I get the error 1004 Method Range of object _Worksheet failed

*I am still using my original copySheet.range... code to get the error.  When I use BruceWayne's code, I still just get a "0"

Comment: @Haley - Try replacing the `.Formula` line with this one: `addSection.Formula = "=""DataInput_""&SUBSTITUTE('Add Extra Section'!$C$3,"" "","""")"`. I tested with a named range `DataInput_OilFurnace` and the cell correctly filled in with the named range.  This is with `Oil Furnace` in `'Add Extra Section'!C3`.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately still getting a "0" when I replace it.  I am using only the code you have written: pasteSheet.Cells(pasteSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = addSection.Value

Comment: @Haley - What are you expecting the formula to return? `DataInput_OilFurnace`, correct? (Again, assuming that `Oil Furnace` is in cell C3 on your "Add Extra Section" sheet) ...I think there may be a circle here, since the formula is going into "Add Extra Section" Cell C3.  Change `Set addSection` to `Set addSection = copySheet.Range("C3")` and see if that helps.

Comment: It worked!  You are a wonderful person!  Thank you!  

If I could trouble you a bit more...I am not sure why it works.  Set addSection = copySheet.range("C3") -->  To make sure I understand it, we are telling excel to look in the copy sheet at cell C3, but then immediately replacing that with the addSection.Formula?  I guess I am confused about where the "C3" goes?

But again, thank you!

Comment: @Haley - See my edit, I *hope* I made it a little more clear. Let me know if you're still confused! Also, a nice tip for learning VBA is that you can press `F8` to walk through a macro, line by line, and watch what's happening in Excel as it happens.

Comment: @Haley - You're very welcome!! See my last edit though, I think it would probably be a better way to do this. *I* think it's even more clear, and you don't have to use the worksheet. Just grab the string, remove the spaces, and put it in the destination cell.  Note that you won't have "DataInput_[range name]" in the DataInput sheet, but AFAIK you don't really need that. You're only doing that so you can then copy/paste.